# When a wife asks her husband, "is YOUR daughter home yet?", does this make you conclude that she isn't THEIR daughter but only his?

Tags: meaning, expressions, connotation

In my native language when I say to my husband "is your daughter home" it's just another way of saying "is my daughter home", no difference. Although sometimes it might mean that me and my daughter have been quarreling lately. But it is very unlikely the case that it means she isn't my daughter. (divorce and people living with step parents is very uncommon in my society).

Comment: If the "your" is stressed as in the title, it implies to me that the speaker feels the husband isn't fulfilling his duties towards his daughter but the interpretation is subjective.

Comment: Most people would use the daughter's name, whatever the family circumstances, but expressions like 'your daughter' are occasionally used to imply a humorous disapproval of the person in question. "I'm annoyed with her so I'm referring to her as _your_ child and not _mine_."

Comment: I think the two usages in the comments above pretty much cover it, and I'd just add that the word "your" stands out enough on its own that I don't think it needs to be stressed in either case to achieve this kind of commentary.

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback. Just want clarify that the stressing was just something I added for you to understand my question. In the original text "your" is not stressed.

Comment: You can use "your"+relative to express something positive too, suggesting "you should be proud of your daughter." This is more commonly used with children where you say "Give this to your father/grandfather" or "Your grandfather was a hero during the war" or "Your baby brother is coming home from hospital".

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.

The stressing of "your" in this sentence is more likely a expression of slight annoyance at the tardiness of the daughter than the wife implying that she is not her parent. "My kids when they are good, your kids when they're naughty" is a rather common occurrence

It can also be (depending on context) that the daughter went to the husband for permission to go out that was previously denied by the wife - husband granted permission with a time limit and now that she is late, the wife is placing accountability on the husband for that - but not overly worried.

Example:
D = Daughter, W = Wife (mom), H = Husband (dad)

D: Hey mom, can I go out with my friends for dinner and a movie today?

W: No, you have to be at school early tomorrow for [insert appointment here]

D: Dad, I want to go out for dinner and a movie with my friends, but mom said no... please, it is the premiere...

H: I don't see any harm in letting you go, just be back by 11, ok?

Then 11 comes and goes, daughter is nowhere to be seen. After a while, W asks "Is YOUR daughter home yet?"

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to note is that two people who are raising a child together almost always know whose child that is: *my/your/our*, taken literally, is thus never needed to covey any new information. Most of the time none of these words will be used and the child will be referred to, within the family, by the name or a nickname. When *my/your/our* is used in these contexts it is not to convey information but to express an emotion: *our* expresses a joy or pride in our jointly raising such a wonderful child, *your* expresses some emotional distancing from (or a displeasure with) the child or the other parent's relationship with child, while *my* emotionally affirms my relationship with the child combined with the distancing from the other parent. The emotions in question need not be very strong: thus, while *your* and *my* may occasionally be used in the context of a serious fight with one's spouse, they are often used playfully, to express a very mild rebuke.

All this has very little do with whether the child is biologically a child of both spouses (and thus with the prevalence of stepparenthood in a society). Two people who are committed to raising a child together will generally use or not use *my/your/our* for the child in the same way as biological parents would, without regard to which one of them is the biological parent and which one is the stepparent. If anything, people living in such households are less likely to use *my* or *your* in the way that reflects the biological relationships, for fear that, in their circumstances, the emotional distancing involved may seriously hurt the other spouse or the child.